# SQL Database does not show up after copying it to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB in "sql server object explorer" visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016

After the Crash of my Laptop I was able to recover the data that I had on the hard drive. In the meantime I have a new Laptop and I'm restoring my last ASP.NET MVC Core Project in Visual Studio 2015 (Community).
In this Project I've created a database using EF Core Code First.
In SQL Server Object Explorer (on my old Laptop) the database was showing up.
Visual Studio saved the data under the path "C:\Users\USERNAME".

In `appsetting.json` the Connection string was `"DATABASEDbConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DATABASE_v1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`.

My new Laptop has the exact Name of the old one.
I've copied the database in the same Location as before.

But:

1. the database does not Show up in SQL Server Object Explorer, and I have no idea how to bind it again
2. if I try to run my Project I get this error:

   SqlException: Cannot open database "DATABASE_v1" requested by the login. The login failed Login failed for user 'USER-PC\USER.

How can I bind again my database?

Comment: Did you try to Right click on 'Databases' folder under `MSSQLLocalDB` and select the 'Add new database' option?

Comment: Hi James, the database already exists. I do not Need to recreate it again. I want to restore it.

Comment: Yes I understand, but in that option I think you can just select the existing .mdf file.

Comment: I've tried it out, and unfortunately it does not work. I get the message that the database already exists. There is not an Option to bind an existing db; only creating a new one is supported

Comment: Try 'Add SQL server' - Then under browse select `MSSQLLocalDB` from Local and at the bottom you can select a Db name - is your listed?

Comment: I James, my database is not listed.

Comment: I have copied it to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA and also to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB .... no way

Comment: I assume you were using Windows Authentication to access it. I'm guessing that because you are trying to access it on another PC with different user name, password it will not allow access.

Comment: PC Name is exactly the same, also the Password is the same. The big question ist how can I reconnect? localdb seems not to see my database, even if it is located at the right place

Answer (score 0):

After googling a couple of hours, I've found the solution.
I started Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and added a reference to `(localdb)\MSSQLLOcalDB` and from there it was possible to bind my database located in `C:\Users\USERNAME`.

The `localdb` instance in VS seems to be influenced by SQL Server Management Studio. The latter rules binding to user's DBs.

I'm wondering why `localdb` does not start authomatically when running SQL Server Management Studio.